# Sql server 2005 - How to generate XML for this hierarchical data

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I have three tables :-

Parent - Which contains some properties, an Item collection and a collection of children

Child  - Which contains some properties and an Item collection

Item   - Which contains some properties

The relationship is depicted in the below XML structure.

```
<Mapping>
    <Parent1>
        <Property1></Property1>
        <Property2></Property2>
        <Property3></Property3>
            <Parent1Children>
                <Child1>
                    <Child1Property1></Child1Property1>
                    <Child1Property2></Child1Property2>
                    <Parent1SomeCollection>
                    <ChildItem1>
                        <Item1Property1></Item1Property1>
                        <Item1Property2></Item1Property2>
                    </Item2>
                    <ChildItem2>
                        <Item2Property1></Item2Property1>
                        <Item2Property2></Item2Property2>
                    </ChildItem2>
        </Parent1SomeCollection>
                </Child1>
                <Child2>
                <Child2Property1></Child2Property1>
                <Child2Property2></Child2Property2>
                </Child2>
            </Parent1Children>  
        <Parent1SomeCollection>
            <Item1>
                <Item1Property1></Item1Property1>
                <Item1Property2></Item1Property2>
            </Item2>
            <Item2>
                <Item2Property1></Item2Property1>
                <Item2Property2></Item2Property2>
            </Item2>
        </Parent1SomeCollection>    
    </Parent1>  
</Mapping>
```

Could anyone help me in writing a FOR XML query to generate this XML structure?